# user profile in a view with inline editing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'd like to get the user profile with a view (works, no problem). But I also would like to get an 'edit' link next to every user profile field for direkt editing.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create view with settings:

- Show: users
- Display format : unformatted list of fields

Then on view editing page:

- add field (press the button)
- select "User: Edit link"
- uncheck "Create a label "
- define "Edit user" to option "Text to display"

Comment: I can't see the edit link. Do I need any access right? The user has all rights to edit all own fields.

Comment: Not sure what exact permission is needed for that. Check this.. read comments: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39127/permission-settings-for-edit-node-link-to-show-up